# Error in dataframe:undefined columns selected

Tags: r, r-caret

CODE:

```
library(caret); library(kernlab); data(spam)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=spam$type,
p=0.75, list=FALSE)
training <- spam[inTrain,]
testing <- spam[-inTrain,]

M <- abs(cor(training[,-58]))
diag(M) <- 0
which(M > 0.8,arr.ind=T)

preProc <- preProcess(log10(spam[,-58]+1),method="pca",pcaComp=2)
spamPC <- predict(preProc,log10(spam[,-58]+1))

preProc <- preProcess(log10(training[,-58]+1),method="pca",pcaComp=2)
trainPC <- predict(preProc,log10(training[,-58]+1))
modelFit <- train(training$type ~ .,method="glm",preProc = "pca",data=trainPC)
```

When is execute this following error occurs:

```
Error in [.data.frame(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) :
undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include a clear problem description. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your code.

1. you are using multiple pca preprocessing steps on the training data. First as a separate preprocess, then again in the train function. This is not necessary. You can use the preproc option to do everything in one go. The advantage of using it in train is that if you start doing predictions the new data will be handled correctly. Otherwise you need to run your test / new data first through the preproc predict before the model predict.
2. You specify the formula in train as training$type and you specify the data part as trainPC. That doesn't work as you are now taking data from 2 data.frames.

The following code will do what you intend to do. the glm method will specify the family argument itself if y is a factor. But it is better to specify it yourself.

```
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=spam$type,
                               p=0.75, list=FALSE)
training <- spam[inTrain,]
testing <- spam[-inTrain,]


modelFit <- train(type ~ ., 
                  data = training,
                  method = "glm",
                  preProc = "pca",
                  family = binomial)
```

You will get some warnings like below. But you will get those as well if you just run a glm.

> glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred